# Laravel 8 CRUD Edit page cannot display correctly

Tags: php, html, laravel, crud, laravel-8

I am currently making laravel project using internet references and now I'm stuck at CRUD operation.

I use Laravel 8 with jetstream for auth, now ui template assets, bootstrap.

I tried several CRUD codes from different sources and everything worked except for edit page.

**Index page**: [image]

**Edit page**: [image]

This is my route:

```
Route::resource('projects', ProjectController::class);
```

My controller:

```
 public function edit(Project $project)
{
    return view('projects.edit', compact('project'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'introduction' => 'required',
        'location' => 'required',
        'cost' => 'required'
    ]);
    $project->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('projects.index')
        ->with('success', 'Project updated successfully');
}
```

The blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Edit Product</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('projects.index') }}" title="Go back"> <i class="fas fa-backward "></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form action="{{ route('projects.update', $project->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Name:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $project->name }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Introduction:</strong>
                    <textarea class="form-control" style="height:50px" name="introduction"
                        placeholder="Introduction">{{ $project->introduction }}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Location:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $project->location }}"
                        value="{{ $project->location }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Cost:</strong>
                    <input type="number" name="cost" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $project->cost }}"
                        value="{{ $project->location }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
@endsection
```

I tried changing the edit blade file codes to different ones but still same. I tried different method from online for the edit function in controller but nothing change. I also tried completely different coding, different model controllers and all, still the same. Only edit page turns out that way. Anyone have any clue?

Comment: Is it the layout you're having problems with, or are you having problems with the actual editing process?

Comment: the layout because the edit process works fine.

Comment: The issue then is with HTML/CSS:You have CSS classes on each row, but you have nothing to format/separate out your Strong elements (which should be labels, by the way) and your inputs. The page will only be formatted in the way that **you** tell it.

Comment: i also tried with completely different html for the edit blade file but still the same. i tried with empty page but with certain layout also the same. I tried with the index page, show page html and it also display error just like the pics above.

Comment: I don't see any errors, but possible a missing CSS file. Check the Network tab of your developer console to see if the CSS is throwing a 404, and if the path is wrong.

Comment: ouhh yes yes, i just checked them and there's error. Thank you. Currently trying to find out how to solve it.

Comment: The problem is not on your index and create page?